# Apache Flink: Will processing only one Side Output cause memory issues on unused Side Outputs?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm filtering a stream using [Side Outputs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/side_output/). I'll be processing one side output, but wanted to know how Flink will handle the unused side output. Will Flink's Garbage Collection take care of it? If not, what's the best practice to manage the unused side output in case it causes memory exceptions over time?

Comment: What do you mean by “unused side output?” Are you sending output to a tag that isn’t connected to anything?

Comment: Correct. I am splitting the stream into two output tags. I have a property on startup that determines which tag to use to write to a sink. This leaves one output tag not connected to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to worry. The events sent to the disconnected side output won't consume any resources.